# Disable Syntax Error "Symbol <id> could not be resolved" for some symbols in Eclipse Plugin using CDT

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

In my eclipse plugin I want to support my tool's language which extends C++ with some keywords and concepts. My language class, editor class and source parser class are all inheriting CDT classes for C++. I can parse the keywords and add nodes for them to the AST. But some of my keywords/commands the editor will always mark as "Symbol could not be resolved".

Example:
There is a command "@result" which returns the result of a last computation as an enum value that is defined in some header file in the tool's core.

```
typedef enum {
    OK = 0;
    WARNING = 1;
    ERROR = 2;
} errCode_t;
```

So the command `@result` returns 0, 1 or 2. But inside the editor the command is marked as `Symbol '@result' could not be resolved`. No I want to tell the Indexer to not try to resolve this very token.

In the Preprocessor class I could change the token type from `IToken.tIDENTIFIER` to, say, 50000. What I try to achieve by that is something like

```
if (token.getType() == 50000) {
    // don't try to resolve symbol
    return null;
} else {
    return super.resolveSymbol();
}
```

Is there a way to do that? I think my first problem is that I don't understand who or what is responsible for the Syntax Error Marking (maybe the Indexer?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors of the form `Symbol ... could not be resolved` are produced by CDT's Code Analysis component, specifically `ProblemBindingChecker`, which traverses the AST and reports the error for any `IASTName` which resolves (via `IASTName.resolveBinding()`) to a `ProblemBinding`.

It is only `IASTName` nodes which resolve to bindings, so if you are getting this error for your `@result` token, that suggests the parser is building an `IASTName` node for it. I'm not sure how that's happening if you've changed the token type, I suppose it depends on how you handle the new token type in your extended parser.

Comment: The note about changing the token type was a bit misleading. The problem actually comes when the token is a IToken.tIDENTIFIER.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me solve this issue. I have (a) written a subclass NodeFactory that creates (b) a subclass NameNode which (c) overrides resolveBinding() to check whether "name" is "@result" and if yes, returns null, otherwise what super does.