# Disable or skip parsing of some token in C/C++ language (Eclipse plugin, using CDT)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Following this question [disable-syntax-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112132/disable-syntax-error-symbol-id-could-not-be-resolved-for-some-symbols-in-ecl), I need something really similar.

I have my set of eclipse plugins and I want to support my own language which extends C++ with some keywords and concepts.
For example:

```
int i = @$symbol;
```

the identifier **@$symbol** is defined somehere else, and literally substituted from my custom compiler before the real C code gets to the C compiler.

Now I need some basic guideline to what class override in CDT codebase, to get rid of "Symbol could not be resolved".
The answer to the post [disable-syntax-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112132/disable-syntax-error-symbol-id-could-not-be-resolved-for-some-symbols-in-ecl) is not clear to me.. I need some basic information or good practice on how to extend the CDT, maybe some kind of tutorial.

Thank you

Comment: The reply is referring to a CODAN checker, i.e. what you can see under Code Analisys preferences of a c/c++ project. One of the checker is the problem binding checker, if you disable that checker you won't see anymore "symbol could not be resolved".

Comment: OK but I need a way to programmatically disable those warnings, and to extend other functionalities. From what I see in the CDT code, I need to extend the CDT parser and the CPreprocessor class at least, but I can't find any guideline or help on this...